# How to set timing mode on SKTransition

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am using SKTransition in order to move between SpriteKit scenes:

```
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition 
                                moveInWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown 
                                duration:0.3];

    transition.pausesOutgoingScene = YES;

    SKScene *endGameScene = [[EndGameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];

    [self.view presentScene:endGameScene transition:transition];
```

The transition is linear and I wish to set a timing mode such as ease-out to make it look better. However, I could not find any reference for timing mode in SKTransitions. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that there is no ease in / ease out in the current SKTransition class. Short of you designing a new transition class from the ground up, I have not come across anyone else posting a workable solution for this issue.

Not knowing your code or intentions, this suggestion might be irrelevant... you could consider doing some fancy footwork with the `pausesIncomingScene` and `pausesOutgoingScene`. All dependent on your desired effect of course.